# two level tabs jquery

Tags: jquery, css, tabs

I need to have two level tab navigation.

Basically like this:

Tab1 Tab2 Tab3

TabA TabB TabC

When user clicks for example Tab2 he then can choose again from 2nd level tabs (TabA, TabB etc).

I can make the first level ok but I can't make the 2nd level. How can i put it in the first level tabs.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please don't forget to visit http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: http://apricotstudios.wordpress.com/2008/08/29/jquery-tabs-tutorial/ i have used this tutorial to make the one level tab nav

Answer (score 5):

Just nest the second set of tabs within the first set inside your html like so:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tab-1"><span>One</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-2"><span>Two</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-3"><span>Three</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tab-1">
      <p>First tab is active by default.</p>
      <p>Second tab contains nested tabs.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab-2">
      <!-- Nested Tabs! -->
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#nested-1"><span>One</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#nested-2"><span>Two</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#nested-3"><span>Three</span></a></li>
      </ul>
      <div id="nested-1">
        Nest tab 1 content: Onerem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy..
      </div>
      <div id="nested-2">
        Nest tab 2 content: Tworem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy..
      </div>
      <div id="nested-3">
        Nest tab 3 content: Threm ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy..
      </div>
      <!-- End Nested Tabs -->
      Regular tab 2 content (optional)
    </div>
    <div id="tab-3">
        <p>Second tab contains multiple tabs.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

..and initialize them both on document ready like so:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
    $("#tab-2").tabs();
  });
</script>
```

When in doubt, check out the jQuery tabs api documentation at http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs